# Range of csv2cell

Tags: csv, octave

I have to import CSV files into Octave, and since the files are very long *and* very wide, it takes very very long.

Could it be faster if I imported only a subset of the data? I do not need all of the columns.

Example `test.csv` (added blanks for readability):

```
Name,Age,Weight,Size,PhoneNumber,Gender
John, 12,    12, 120,  120120120, m
Mary, 13,    13, 130,  130130130, f
Knut, 14,    14, 140,  140140140, m
```

Example import:

```
csv_data = csv2cell("test.csv");
```

When I only want `Name` and `Gender`, what `range` argument can I add to the `csv2cell` call?

Comment: do a preprocessing with awk to filter the columns you need

Comment: Are you on GNU/Linux? Then it's easy to preprocess with cut vor awk.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm on Windows. But please leave your answer where it is, it is a very valuable source of Octave knowledge as well. :-)

Answer (score 0):

This shows how to call `cut` to preprocess the data:

```
#!/usr/bin/env octave

clear all
pkg load io

test_fn = "test.csv";
n = 1e6;

#unlink (test_fn);

## Create testfile if nonexistent
if (!exist (test_fn, "file"))

  printf ("Create test file '%s'...\n", test_fn);
  fflush (stdout);
  fid = fopen (test_fn, "w");

  fputs (fid, "Name,Age,Weight,Size,PhoneNumber,Gender\n");

  for k=1:n
    fputs (fid, "John,12,12,120,120120120,m\n");
    fputs (fid, "Mary,13,13,130,130130130,f\n");
    fputs (fid, "Knut,14,14,140,140140140,m\n");
  endfor

  fclose (fid);
endif

tic
  c = csv2cell (test_fn);
  name1 = c(:,1);
  gender1 = c(:,6);
toc

## preprocess
tic
  tmp_fb = tempname();
  cmd = ['cut -d "," -f1,6 "' test_fn '" > "' tmp_fb '"'];
  system (cmd);
  c = csv2cell (tmp_fb);
  unlink (tmp_fb);
  name2 = c(:,1);
  gender2 = c(:,2);
toc

assert (name1, name2);
assert (gender1, gender2);
```

gives

```
Elapsed time is 4.42117 seconds.
Elapsed time is 2.83609 seconds.
```

so, approx. 66% execution time